# How to rotate the image in the right direction by clicking on top of image?

Tags: html, css, rotation

I want to rotate the image in the right direction by clicking on above of image for my website
For example, if my head is below of picture,
i clicking on below of image
and The image rotating 90 degrees for the correct position

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=rotate+image+on+click+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Example to rotate image 90deg as following jquery code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").click(function(){
         $(this).rotate(90);
    });
 });
```